# Path with blank spaces and hyphen "-" using AppleScript

Tags: path, applescript, spaces, save-as

I'm trying to save the document using the following path and name:

```
set outpath to "Dropbox/PHY101 - Current/" & "E1S1.pdf"
```

However, due to the blank spaces this doesn't work.
I tried using:

```
PHY101\\ -\\ Current and PHY101\ -\ Current
```

None of them worked.

This is the rest of the code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set activeDoc to active document
    save as activeDoc file name outpath file format format PDF
end tell
```

Comment: You still have some spaces to escape.  You can also use the `quoted form` property.

Comment: What would be the quoted form?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just adding more ampersands:

```
PHY101" & " - " & "Current
```

But I still don't understand why the other approach doesn't work.